# store tabular data other than in data table using c#

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary, datatable, store

i have some tabular data in c# having around 100 K(100000) records which i have to store in memory. What is the best way to store this data other than in table format keeping in mind i have filter out result which is based on some conditions ( like dt.select("field1=1 and...) ,sorting resultset just like SQL table.

kindly suggest any other way to retrieve data.Dictionary is another way but based on field conditions how to retrieve data if using Dictionary or any other collections.

Comment: `which i have to store in memory`, are you sure about that statement? I say that because you also said `keeping in mind i have filter out result which is based on some conditions`.

Comment: Did you actually check how long it takes to run your query if storing everything in a simple `List`? 100K items sounds like a lot, but maybe it is not...

Comment: means this tabular resultset is loaded when application is up and used during the operation... hope u get this....

Comment: What do you mean with "best way"? The way to spare memory? The fastest way to load? The fastest way to query?

Comment: What's the question actually? Can you show sample data and what you have tried to filter it?  What do you want to know? "How to retrieve data", you haven't shown how you retrieve data, how should we suggest a better way? Filter or fill a `DataTable` or a `Dictionary`. The question is rather confusing.

Comment: Would you be better served in creating a class to represent each row and just have `List<MyRowClass>` or something

Comment: Martin... it means both ...not to use cpu memory as well as query it is real time application

Comment: If it is real-time, then show us some sample data and **the kind of queries you will run**. Otherwise, there is no simple answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you go for speed an low on memory consumption, try this:

1. Create a model class which contains a property for each
   column in the source table. This is your entity.
2. Read from the source table (if it comes from a database, use a `DataReader`). Read the data record by record and for each record, create an entity. During reading each field of type string, you can optimize a little bit:

   - Optimize for speed: read the string and put it directly into the property of the entity.
   - Optimize for memory: read the string, use `String.Intern` on it and put in into the property.
3. Store all these entities in a collection. Here you have two choises:

   - Use a `List<Entity>` to store it all. You can use LINQ on the list and entities to query your collection. This is rather slow on performance but the best solution for memory.
   - If you know in advance which queries/criteria you are going to use, use one dictionay for a set of criteria. For example. If you have the properties "FirstName" and "LastName", make a dictionary which will store your entity as a value and a `Tuple<string, string>` which the values of the FirstName and LastName. Now it is extremely fast to query on these values. For sorting, use the `SortedDictionary`. If a key has duplicates, create a dictionary like this: `Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, List<Entity>>` which will store all records with the same matching first- and last names. I know this solution requires more coding, but is pretty fast.

Of course you can keep the `DataTable` solution. If memory is your only concern, try to make a `DataReader`-wrapper which will `Intern` all strings. Wrap your wrapper arround the original `DataReader` and use it to create / fill the `DataTable`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion....but no major performance changes if storing values in List.

Comment: How did you measure the performance in both situations? With a stopwatch-class? I am curious for your results.